# How to create react components so that each component has a unique id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I want to tract my components by their id, so I want to ensure each component of a certain class to have a unique id.

Should I use [higher order components](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775)?

Or create a factory function:

```
nextID = 1;
function ComponentFactory(props) {
  return (
    <Component id={nextID++} {...props}/>
  );
}
```

This approach is not pretty because I can't use `<>` angle brackets to create the component.

My use case is:

- I have a list of Todos where each Todo should be placed on a specific coordinate.
- A TodoList component holds the state of coordinates for each Todo item by associating a coordinate with the Todo `ID`.
- Later I want to add a new Todo, I update my store to add the new todo.
- TodoList component looks up the `ID` of each Todo Item and finds a specific coordinate for that item.
- If it can't find a coordinate for a certain ID, then it randomly assigns a new coordinate.

Comment: How does using generated IDs help you without tracking what element got which ID? What's the point of this?

Comment: I don't know I thought it would be helpful later @MadaraUchiha

Comment: It will not be helpful without a way of tracking which element got which ID. An ID is used for uniquely identifying elements/components across the page. Which doesn't seem to be the case here. So in your case, it won't be helpful at all.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I added my use case see my edited question please.

Comment: The parent component could carry an array of all Todo’s, from there you can use the index to make references to each todo component. No need to use DOM attributes.

Comment: I wanted to keep a seperate array synced with todo items that represents the coordinates of each item, then each todo needs an id for add/remove to work. Now I solved this by keeping the coordinates along with the todo items in the store.@David